# Modify column name from rmysql without value changes in the table

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I want to change my column name in the table stored in mysql without changes in the rest data....

I tried doing by ALTER TABLE command

```
dbSendQuery(con, paste0("ALTER TABLE demographic  MODIFY " , first_field , " bill_no INT"))
```

Answer (score 2):

To rename a column in MySQL, use `CHANGE` rather than `MODIFY`:

```
ALTER TABLE demographic  CHANGE COLUMN " , first_field , " bill_no INT"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **sp_rename**

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'TableName.OldColumnName' , 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'
```

In your example:

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'demographic.first_field' , 'bill_no', 'COLUMN'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the method in SQL Server, but the question is explicitly about MySQL.

Comment: np, I should have focused on mysql. Glad you solved your doubt :)